# Unable to multiply two variables in Smarty on Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

In my prestashop store, I have two variables `per_sqft_price` and `per_box_price`. per_sqft_price is having currency (`$`) sign before. I am trying to print the multiplied value of those 2 variables. But it is always printing 0.

```
{assign var = per_sqft_price value = $product.price}
{assign var = per_box_price value = $product.features[0].value}

<meta itemprop="per_sqft_price" content="{$per_sqft_price|replace:'$':''}"/>
{math equation = "x * y" x = $per_sqft_price  y = $per_box_price }
```

Please help me how can i solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you var_dump `per_sqft_price` and `per_box_price` please (after `assing`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$product.price_amount` instead of `$product.price`, it gives numeric price output without currency sign. And be sure that `$product.features[0].value` is numeric as well, because it may be a string and may contain just a text. Also, you can use `intval` for your variables like:

```
{math equation = "x * y" x = $per_sqft_price|intval  y = $per_box_price|intval }
```

Comment: Its working. How to make the result upto 2 decimal places?

Comment: Use floatval instead of intval or add  number_format:2 to the result if you need to have 2 numbers after period

Comment: {math assign='result' equation = "x * y" x = $per_sqft_price|floatval  y = $per_box_price|floatval }
          {$result|number_format:2}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
{$result = ($per_sqft_price|intval) * ($per_box_price|intval)}
```

It's not a standard way but it may work

Comment: I edited the question. Can u please recheck it. Actually the number format is restricting to do math operation.

Comment: Tried using your way. Still showing empty or 0 after math operation.